# Image view not centered in parent though layout_centerHorizontal is set to true

Tags: android, android-layout

Why is my image view (orange) not centered in the horizontal linear layout (blue) even though its layout_centerHorizontal is set to true:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_square" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6dbdff"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#ff5831"
            android:layout_weight="0.37" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_width from linearLayout that wrap your imageView also must to be wrap_content, so it will disappear your blue font, so you can wrap this linearLayout with a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use layout_centerHorizontal for a child of a Linear layout... this is the proper implementation. Notice how i use the gravity attribute. (the one you're using would work if it was a direct child of a RelativeLayout

(Edit to work...)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="HELLO" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6dbdff"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.315"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="#ff5831"
            android:layout_weight="0.37" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Alternative, in case you don't want to put things on either side of the image...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="HELLO" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6dbdff"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#ff5831" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I replace layout_centerHorizontal with layout_gravity="center_horizontal" there is no change, the image is still on the left

Comment: Just fixed it for you to work WITH the layout weight you specified.

http://puu.sh/jbhv3/6c985a4b15.png

Keep in mind, this is with the assumption that you want to add items on the left/right of the centered view.

Comment: Why is the addition of the View element necessary? (BTW the layout weights were all added automatically by Android Studio, I just dragged and dropped the image view into the layout)

Comment: layout weights are like percentages. So think of it like so, if the parent of 3 views has a weightsum of 3.

It's children each have a layout_weight of 1, that means that each of the children holds exactly 33.3333% of the parent's width/height, meaning you could set each of the children's layout_width to "0dp" and they'd still be visible. 

Alternatively i can do a parent with say 100 weight sum, have 5 children, each with weight 20, each one of those will have 20% of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need the 2nd LinearLayout, so here goes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_square" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="#ff5831"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.37" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For now,  I'made the src of the image the color you want to see. IF you replace it with an actual bitmap refernce,  it will be centered and properly sized based on the bitmap you use and parent restraints

> if I delete the android:layout_weight="0.37" line (which was added by
>   Android Studio) then the image view vanishes, why is that?

With this line,  the imageView will know how to size itself based on the parent.  Without, because the imageView has no image,  so it cannot size itself based on the image bitmap to show (which is missing) and the parent that contains it. Add an image to show and it will come back.

Final advice,

Totally read this article about [how android draws views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html). Its really really great info.

Comment: if you need the blue coloring in your example...lemme know I will revise.

Comment: I'm using a nested linear layout as I'm planning on putting several smaller images on either side of the central main image and I though a horizontal liner layout would be a good way of grouping these as they will not be vertically centered within the main layout but offset slightly.